# How to set color in plot for Hierarchical clustering

Tags: r

I have data matrix as flowing :

```
> dim(data)
[1] 360  91
```

the last columns of it is factor(1,2,3,...,15) and it's represent the classes. I want to do Hierarchical clustering, but I don't know to set different color to the points for different classes in the plot. I've tried this :

```
# assigning color code to data
data.df = data.frame(data[,1:90])
Color<-data[,91]
data.df$Color <- as.factor(Color)

data.norm <- as.data.frame(scale(data.df[,1:90]))

# clustering: 
  dist.euclid <- dist(data.norm, method="euclidean")
  hc.euclid.single <- hclust(dist.euclid, method="single")

png("HClust, Euclidean distance, Single Linkage.png")
  plot(hc.euclid.single,  main="HClust, Euclidean distance, Single Linkage" , col=data.df$Color)
  dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ape package has some nice tree plotting functions. Try something like this:

```
library(ape)
ph <- as.phylo(hc.euclid.single)    
plot(ph,  main="HClust, Euclidean distance, Single Linkage", tip.color=data.df$Color,
     direction = "downwards"))
```